# Bootstrap 4.5 grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some weird issue... I wanted to create some kind of webshop. So I have 1 row with 4 columns (4 products) and I also using Bootstrap 4.5, here is what is happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRw0p.png)

Simple issue picture won`t fit inside but space between boxes is not getting smaller why? And how can I resize this boxes? To be wider and to get small space between them? Here is code:

```
<section>
      <div class="container products">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-2 item">
                <img src="/img/product.png" alt="product">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1 item">
                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1 item">
                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1 item">
                  
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Try adding the class `img-fluid` to the image

Comment: It is working nice. Thanks but now how I can make this box wider? It too narrowly...

Comment: `col-md-2` is setting the with. Two columns out of 12 per row. So you have four divs, each taking up two columns, which leaves you with four left over unused columns. You can try changing `col-md-2` to `col-md-3`

Comment: Okey I did that too. But then there is no space between boxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove `offset-md-1` class and add margin to `item` class. If you want to make the blocks wider change `col-md-2` to `col-md-3`